# How can I add custom command dynamicly? I am using cloudify 2.7.1

Tags: cloudify

I how a scenario that need add cumstom command dynamicly, and did not need to restart agent and usm, how to do this ?
thanks you very much! Steve

Answer (score 0):

Cloudify 2 does not support adding custom commands dynamically. That said, you can certainly have a custom command that receives a string parameter and evaluates it as a groovy expression, allowing you to run any code you want.

You can also have a custom command that gets a url parameter, downloads it as an executable script and executes it. So you can certainly execute dynamic code if your recipe wants to explicitly support this.